# Why linux popularity is going down?

Tags: linux

why linux popularity goes down but softwares come to linux more and more?[source](https://netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?options=%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22%24and%22%3A%5B%7B%22deviceType%22%3A%7B%22%24in%22%3A%5B%22Desktop%2Flaptop%22%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22dateLabel%22%3A%22Custom%22%2C%22attributes%22%3A%22share%22%2C%22group%22%3A%22platform%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22share%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%22platformsDesktop%22%2C%22dateInterval%22%3A%22Monthly%22%2C%22dateStart%22%3A%222019-09%22%2C%22dateEnd%22%3A%222019-10%22%2C%22plotKeys%22%3A%5B%7B%22platform%22%3A%22Linux%22%7D%5D%2C%22segments%22%3A%22-1000%22%7D)

Answer (score 5):

Your question is opinionated, and makes assumptions based on statistically irrelevant data from an unknown source, but:

This is only looking at desktop OS usage.  Linux excels as a server OS and is certainly increasing market share in that region.  Additionally note that all android smartphones run on linux so the popularity of linux has increased exponentially since the invention of the smartphone.

The link you provided shows Linux's market share going from 1.8% to 1.55% over the last month these are not really statistically relevant numbers and where are they getting these numbers from anyway?  Have they accounted for all anomalies?

As it turns out they collect this data by analyzing visits to their network of clickbait sites.  Perhaps linux users are simply more computer savvy than windows users and therefore don't frequent sketchy clickbait sites as often?